# ER Diagram : Understanding connections between relationship and entities

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I am trying to understand this diagram and after reading over PowerPoints and the Book I still don't see an answer to my question.

[image]

What is the difference between the single line and the double line connecting the relationship to the entities? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It signifies total participation of Movie in Acts_In. Also known as existence dependency.